# How are primitve/fundamental datatypes in C++ structured?

Tags: c++, class, comparison, primitive-types

As the title says I want to know how primitive/fundamental datatypes in C++ are structured? If I remember right basically when programming I have always treated them like "class objects". So I ask myself if they are structured the same way like for example

```
class int 
{
   //content of int
};
```

After some basic research I don't think primitve datatypes are structured like this. Still I need to know how they are structured.

Comment: Unlike Java, not everything in C++ is derived from some superclass. It is somewhat unclear what you are asking. Please [clarify](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50019686/edit).

Comment: @Ron I think it is fairly obvious what I want to know. Data like classes or structs have some specific structure which I have shown in the question. And I want to know what the structure of primitive datatypes is?

Comment: @Streight Sadly no, it is not clear. If you are drawing parallels between C++ and  some other language you are well advised not to do that.

Comment: @Ron It's only about C++ here. With "class MyDatatype" you create your own Datatype and it is structured like I have shown in my question. Primitive Datatypes on the other hand are preimplemented and I want to know how they are structured (constructed)?

Comment: The "structure" of basic types like `int`, `float`, etc is implementation-defined.   It can - and does - vary between compilers.

Comment: @Streight your issue is that not only are you trying to pull in an understanding from another language into C++; your understanding of that language is wrong.  Primitive types are named that precisely because they have no class wrapping them; and while some languages offer wrappers to assist in various tasks, they are not required when you want to use that primitive type

Comment: @UKMonkey Again, I just want to know how primitive datatypes are structured in C++. Since I don't know I only compared them to classes for an example.
I don't get why some people rate it down. It is a legitimate question and if someone can't answer it he/her should just leave it be.

Comment: @UKMonkey Basically I wanted to know how primitive datatypes are structured in terms of their syntax and therefore compared them to classes. Imo my question is useful and fairly clear and people are to fast to judge.

Comment: @Streight "in terms of their syntax" that's the problem, it's not clear what you want to know.  "and therefore compared them to classes" a class is a class, a primitive is a primitive.  It's like you're asking the difference in engine size between a bicycle and a car.  They both use the road in the same way an int and a class both use memory, but that's about the end of the similarity.

Comment: I'll take a guess at what you are trying to ask and suggest googling for big-endian/little-endian and IEEE 754 for starters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ language has grammar for specifying classes, and the definition of a class can be shown by writing it in C++:

```
class class_type {}; // an example of a class
```

Unlike class types, fundamental types aren't and cannot be defined using the C++ language and as such, it is not possible to show their definition using C++.

The standard specifies the behaviour of fundamental types. Objects of fundamental types occupy some memory storage, and the state of the memory represents some value. Exactly what memory representation has any particular value is not specified by the standard and can be different across separate systems.

Comment: Thx, but this does not show me how the fundamental types are structured, right?

Comment: Ok, that's at least an answer I can accept in future.